# Files do not open when they begin with . on Windows

Tags: linux, windows, windows-10, filesystems, file-management

I noticed that files fail to open if they begin with a dot. I tested `.pptx` files and `.pdf` files, comparing their behavior on Linux and Windows. I created one nearly empty pdf file and one nearly empty pptx file to test all of the scenarios below. I double clicked on all files in GUI to open them.

1. pptx

   a. Windows File Manager - pptx files are set to launch on Microsoft Powerpoint

   ````
    1) document.pptx
        Opens fine
    2) .pptx
        Powerpoint launches, but spits out ```Sorry, PowerPoint can’t read .pptx```
   ````

   b. Linux Nautilus - pptx files are set to launch on Libreoffice Impress

   ```
    1) document.pptx
        Opens fine
    2) .pptx
        Opens fine
   ```
2. pdf

   a. Windows File Manager - pdf files are set to launch on Mozilla Firefox

   ```
    1) document.pdf
        Opens fine
    2) .pdf
        Cannot open .pdf, check your spelling error message pops up, does not open Firefox
   ```

   b. Linux Nautilus - pdf files are set to launch on Evince

   ```
    1) document.pptx
        Opens fine
    2) .pptx
        Opens fine
   ```

It seems that Windows really doesn't want to open files that begin with a dot. Is this a security feature or a bug? Windows 10 21H2, Microsoft Office 2019.

Comment: In my experience, that is normal. Change the filenames to remove the  .   Log in with a Linux USB if necessary.

Comment: According to the documentation filenames beginning with . are allowed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file?redirectedfrom=MSDN#naming-conventions Try using a name that isn't also a valid extension or maybe .pdf.pdf

Answer (score 0):

In Linux, the point is just another character in the file/folder name.

In Windows, the extension after the point determines the application
to use for the file, while the part before the point is the true
document name.

This means that a document whose name is `.pptx` has an extension
that means that PowerPoint is its handler, but no document name,
so the open fails.
The error message you get is a generic one for failed open, so is not
very informative.